# Any Opensource GUI tool or API which shows svn repo details?

Tags: svn

Every 4 months there will be a release for us. We will create a new branch for every release. We would like to have a gui which shows all the details during that release. Like all the code commits, user who committed the code,code commits based on user, code differences,count of no of files modified and what all files modified. Every detail during that release is to be viewed through ui. 
Similarly we will do this for every release.so that they can view and if require compare with previous releases.

Is there any open source GUI which works like above?
Or
If no tool or utility is there, we are planning to write an utility or dashboard which shows above.. Any API which helps me in reading all the above details from the svn repo so that I can show it in my ui

Comment: try installing smartSVN 8

Comment: Looking for open source..smartsvn8 is paid version

Answer (score 1):

Most of the data you are looking for can be read using TortoiseSVN:

- "Show Log" for your development branch will list all commits to that branch. Starting from this dialog, you can get additional information:
- Using the "statistics" button you get some diagrams which show the number of commits of each author
- Selecting all commits (Ctrl+A) will give you the union of all files that changed on your branch
- You can filter the list of commits by author name to obtain the set of files changed by a specific author
- you can even open multiple diff-views at once for all files modified by a specific author. To do so, select all files from the 'show log' dialog and choose 'Show multiple changes...' from the context menu
- the number of modified files can be taken from the status line of the 'show log' dialog.

However, I suspect you'll find this solution unsatisfactory as obtaining the data is not as easy as taking them from a dashboard and a direct comparison to the metrics of a previous releas is impossible.